# How can I add libcrypto dependencies in a Debian package

Tags: ssl, dependencies, debian

If my program depends on libcrypto.so.1.1, is it enough to specify `libssl1.1 (> = 1.1.0)` in `debian/control`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Debian control file dependencies for a program which depends on libcurl.so, libsqlite3.so, libcrypto.so and libpthread.so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44429179) I think *you* are the only one who is going to be able to answer whether you need to depend on that particular version, or whether you will accept newer versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As spelled out in the Debian policy, the package name also specifies the `SONAME` of the library. Thus it should be sufficient to have

```
Depends: libssl1.1
```

without an explicit version specifier. (Also, the space between `>` and `=` in your question looks like a syntax error to me.)

Reference: [6.1 Run-time shared libraries](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-sharedlibs.html#s-sharedlibs-runtime)

Comment: > = ... simply a copy and paste error